# I need help organising these books by topic

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice, book-recommendation, big-picture

Okay, this should be a quick and easy question for those of you who've studied calculus. I have a list of books that I want to order by topic, the books are as follows:

> 1. Michael Spivak - Calculus
> 2. Michael Spivak -
> 3. Tom Apostol - Calculus, Vol. 1
> 4. Tom Apostol - Calculus, Vol. 2
> 5. Richard Courant Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol. 1
> 6. Richard Courant Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol. 2
> 7. Morris Tenenbaum - Ordinary Differential Equations
> 8. Tom Apostol - Mathematical Analysis
> 9. James R. Munkres - Analysis On Manifolds
> 10. Michael Spivak - Calculus On Manifolds
> 11. Morris Tenenbaum - Ordinary Differential Equations
> 12. Richard Haberman - Applied Partial Differential Equations: With Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems
> 13. Robert Strichartz - Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier
> 14. Loomis, Sternberg - Advanced Calculus
> 15. G. H. Hardy - A Course of Pure Mathematics

No I'm not planning on studying all these books, however I do feel it would be nice to have a feel of what's where, and if I do get stuck on one book or the other it would be perhaps be nice to dip into another and see if the exposition is better or see how the expositions differ. At the moment I'm trying to build a mental roadmap of this topic in my head (It's what works for me).

From my very limited knowledge I believe that calculus is ordered and roughly broken up as follows:

> 1. Calculus of one-variable
> 2. Calculus of several-variables
> 3. Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations
> 4. Introductory Analysis? Rigorous Calculus?
> 5. Analysis (However I don't believe very many of the above books are real analysis books)

If this list of topics could be better please amend it.

---

So what I need help with is classifying these books using those topics and these question:

> 1. Is calculus of several variables the same topic as multivariable calculus and is that the same as vector calculus?
> 2. Is the topic of applied differential equations a sub-topic of Ordinary Differential equations?
> 3. Where do partial differential equations fit within this all? Is it it's own topic?
> 4. What is advanced calculus? Is it introductory analysis or what?
> 5. Are there any other canonical books you feel should be added to this list?
> 6. What should I study after Spivak's Calculus?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a helpful resource, is the taxonomy given here: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/index.html

Comment: @Bye_World Calculus on manifolds is on the list. Also when would you it is best to learn Linear Algebra? After spivak's calculus?

Comment: Learn linear algebra either concurrently with calculus or immediately afterward.  Don't start on multivariable or analysis without having had linear algebra.

Comment: @seeker If you'd like an idea of the order that these topics should come in, you could take a look at the (incomplete) answer I gave to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18946/learning-roadmap-request-compiling-a-mathematics-stack-exchange-undergraduate).  If you like it you might want to take a picture of it, though, because that question will likely be closed soon.

Comment: @Bye_World thank you! That's really useful!

Comment: I don't think Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is good to learn from. It's good if you want a quick exposition of material you already mostly know. What you study after Spivak's book depends partly on whether you have a particular field of application in mind. If it's only math, then have a look at the bibliography at the end of Spivak's book after you're done reading it. If you don't know what you want to read next, then the default choice would be algebra. For people interested in pure math, it's best to combine linear algebra and abstract algebra in the same exposition. Artin's book...

Comment: ... *Algebra* is great, in my opinion. In fact, if you read the first four chapters of Spivak's book (3rd edition) and find that it's not excessively difficult for you, then it ought to be possible to start Artin's book then, if you're interested. *Clarification*: Above I meant after Spivak's *Calculus*.

Comment: @user204305 I've read Artin's book is extremely rigorous and wouldn't be such a great first exposition to the subject, do you have any other algebra books to recommend? When is one ready for Artin's Algebra, what are the prerequisites?

Comment: In terms of factual knowledge, there are no specific prerequisites for Artin's book, other than knowing what the real numbers are. It helps, but isn't strictly necessary, to have seen vectors. It does require some "mathematical maturity", but as I said, if you don't have any trouble with the beginning of Spivak, you should be fine with Artin. If Spivak's book is too difficult, then read Apostol's *Calculus* instead. Then re-evaluate after most of the first volume what you want to do next, perhaps a linear algebra book, or even just get your linear algebra from Apostol.

Comment: A correction. For Artin's book, you need to know about complex numbers and induction. He writes that you should know calculus too, but this would only be in isolated spots.

Comment: Where do you draw the line between 'Introductory Analysis' and 'Analysis'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't studied all of these, so I'll make this a CW so others can edit in the rest (if they feel like it).

Calculus (just a good calculus reference book, because you don't necessarily need rigor when you're first starting out):

- *Calculus* by Ron Larson & Bruce Edwards

"Rigorous" Single-Variable Calculus (AKA calculus with some analysis):

- *Calculus* by Michael Spivak
- *Calculus, Vol. I* by Tom Apostol (note that Tom's books also cover linear algebra)
- *Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol. I* by Richard Courant

Ordinary Differential Equations:

- *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Morris Tenenbaum
- *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Vladimir I. Arnold

Partial Differential Equations:

- *Applied Partial Differential Equations: With Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems* by Richard Haberman

Real Analysis:

- *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott
- *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom Apostol
- *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin
- *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G.H. Hardy

Multivariable Calculus (just a good first multivariable calculus book, because you don't necessarily need manifold theory when you're first time learning multivariable):

- *Vector Calculus* by Jerrold Marsden & Anthony Tromba

"Rigorous" Multivariable Calculus (AKA multivariable with some analysis and *other* stuff):

- *Calculus, Vol. II* by Tom Apostol
- *Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol. II* by Richard Courant
- *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables* by C.H. Edwards, Jr.

"Rigorous" Multivariable Calculus with some Manifold Theory (Intro to Differential Geometry):

- *Calculus on Manifolds* by Michael Spivak
- *Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach* by Harold Edwards

Analysis on Manifolds:

- *Analysis on Manifolds* by James R. Munkres

Some weird combination of Calculus, Real Analysis, Manifolds, Linear Algebra, and Classical Mechanics:

- *Advanced Calculus* by  Shlomo Sternberg & Lynn Loomis

**NOTE**:  Just because some books are listed in the same category above does not mean that they are at the same level or cover exactly the same topics.  Some of the books above are very different from their neighbors.  If you need help choosing a textbook for self-study, I'd recommend asking your professors -- they will have a better idea of what exactly you already know and what exactly you'll need to know.

**NOTE 2**: Neither the categories nor the books within the categories in the above are ordered in terms of difficulty.

---

Answers to your questions:

> Is calculus of several variables the same topic as multivariable calculus and is that the same as vector calculus?

They all mean the same thing, though not every book on this topic will be at the same level.

> Is the topic of applied differential equations a sub-topic of Ordinary Differential equations?

There are two subfields of differential equations: ordinary differential equations (ODEs) and partial differential equations (PDEs).  Most texts on differential equations will be highly applied because that's the origin of most of the interesting problems of the subject.

> Where do partial differential equations fit within this all? Is it it's own topic?

It is a separate topic from ODEs.  ODEs are about solving differential equations for functions of one variable, while PDEs solves for functions of several variables.

> What is advanced calculus? Is it introductory analysis or what?

A book called "Advanced Calculus" could have several meanings.  Often it is a blend of multivariable calculus and analysis, where analysis is basically just "rigorous" calculus with a little bit of the theory of metric spaces.

> Are there any other canonical books you feel should be added to this list?

I've added a couple, but this is really too many topics for anyone to make a comprehensive list.

> What should I study after Spivak's Calculus?

If you haven't taken linear algebra, yet, that should be your next topic.  If you have, then multivariable calculus (possibly Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*), Real analysis, or ODEs could come next.  Or, if you aren't set on calculus/ analysis, you could go on to Lie theory (a la Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory*), abstract algebra, probability theory, geometry, Clifford algebra, Combinatorics/ Graph Theory, or Elementary Number Theory.  You have a lot of choices once you've gotten the basics (high school math, calculus, and linear algebra) out of the way.

Comment: Hostetter is now out of the trio on Larson and Edward Calculus?

Comment: He is in my copy.

Comment: He is in my copy too but the new edition doesn't list him. I only looked since you only listed Larson and Edwards.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that he is *NOT LISTED* in my copy.  I have the $9$th edition here.

Comment: @Bye_World another question sorry, what is calculus of variation? And where does it fit?

Comment: @seeker Calculus of variations is the study of optimization of functionals.  If you're studying physics, you'd be interested to know that it is the basis of analytic mechanics.  If not, I'd say don't worry about it until/ unless you need it.

Comment: I think of vector calculus as relating specifically to grad, div and curl.

Comment: @user204305 The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus) would agree would you, but it does mention that `The term "vector calculus" is sometimes used as a synonym for the broader subject of multivariable calculus`.  So if you'd like to edit the post, you can.  I specifically made this a community wiki.

Comment: @Bye_World how would you order topics such as: linear algebra; vectors and matrices; groups, field rings; abstract algebra ?

Comment: @seeker Vectors and matrices are subtopics of linear algebra and groups, fields, and rings are subtopics of abstract algebra.  I'd learn linear algebra first, but if you wanted you could just learn the basics of vectors and matrices first and then choose an abstract algebra book that had a pretty good section on linear algebra.

Comment: @Bye_World thanks again!

Comment: @Bye_World I just wanted to drop in to thank you again, your help has been very valuable to me, thank you!